# Windows 7 adhoc network

Tags: windows-7, ad-hoc-network

I have created a wireless adhoc network in windows 7. I have saved the network. Then I pressed connect on this network on my pc and it is displaying `waiting for users`. None of my device is able to connect this wifi hotspot. And my android phone is not even detecting it.

What is wrong? How can I solve it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Android phones are unable to connect to the Adhoc networks. What other devices are you talking about?

Comment: windows phone, a bada os phone

Comment: then there must be an app for connecting to them

Comment: Generaly, mobile devices are having problems with Adhoc networks. You can use VirtualRouter [link](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) or some other alternative to create AP.

Comment: i tried them already but they didn't work so I came to this method

Comment: Some programs don't work on some computers. Have you tried [Conectify](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/?sub=b&utm_expid=22708698-14&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.connectify.me%2F%3Fsub%3Db)?